# The running time of my code in big O time

Tags: c++, performance

So I am doing some practice problems both to better my understanding of code, as well as practice for some upcoming interviews but I am having trouble understanding running time in Big O. The question was:

> You have a staircase with N steps, and you can take any mixture of single and double steps to reach the top. How many different ways can you climb the staircase?

I made a simple answer to the problem

```
//When the function is first called, I set the second argument, x, to 0
int count_steps(int n, int x){
    if(x==n){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(x>n){
        return 0;
    }
    return count_steps(n, x+2) + count_steps(n,x+1);
}
```

If someone could either give me an answer, or a good explanation on how Big O works with recursion I would appreciate it. Also if you have any ideas on more efficient solutions I'd appreciate any kind of hint, because I'm working to improve it too.

Comment: The easiest way to determine the O type of your program is to run it with varying values of N and chart the result. If it looks quadratic, it's *O(n^4)*. If it looks linear, it's *O(n)*. If it's flat it's *O(1)*. There is no such thing as "big O time", as "Big O" is a way of *describing* an approximation of the execution time.

Comment: Your recursive function doesn't seem to terminate. That's O(∞), I think.

Comment: @AlexReynolds It seems to me like it terminates

Comment: [Wiki page for The Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms))

Comment: Note that this function computes the result `R` by adding together `R` copies of `1`. That's a lot of additions. You could probably find another algorithm that doesn't do that; perhaps even a closed form solution. It's often helpful to work through it with small values of `N` to begin with, searching for the pattern

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635893/are-there-any-tools-that-can-determine-perform-code-analysis-for-big-o-complexit

Comment: @Justin, consider the case where n=INT_MAX and x=INT_MAX-1. What happens to x when you call `count_steps` and you've added 2 to x?

Comment: [Dynamic_programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) should reduce the complexity to linear.

Comment: @Jarod42 proven - see below.

Comment: Just check the number of recursive calls required. With no memorization, it's O (n/2) + O (n) which is O (n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer two parts.

**1. What is the running time of the OP's original `count_steps` function?**

**2. How can the running time be improved?**

Since you are always calling initially with X=0, then it's helpful to rewrite the function as:

```
int count_steps(int n){
    if(n==0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(n < 0){
        return 0;
    }
    return count_steps(n-2) + count_steps(n-1);
}
```

Let `T(n)` be the return value of count_steps for a given value of `n`:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)
```

where `T(0)=1` and `T(-1)=0`.

Solve the recurrence `T(n)-T(n-1)-T(n-2) = 0`.  The roots of the characteristic polynomial `x^2-x-1=0` are (1+sqrt(5))/2 and (1-sqrt(5))/2

This should look like the Fibonacci sequence. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number.  And it in fact has a closed form solution. `T(n)=O(Phi^N)` where `Phi=(1+sqrt(5))/2` is the golden ratio about equal to 1.618.

Notice that the running time of the function `count_steps` as originally written, is proportional to the number of times it recurses. (Everything else in the function runs in constant time). **Therefore the running time, *as originally written* is `O(T(n)) = O(Phi^n)`.**

**How can this be improved?** Another answer shows a linear time solution -- which is much better.  But since there is a closed form solution to the recurrence (related to finding the Nth Fibonacci number), **you can improve your function to O(1).**

Comment: I'd be interested to see the O(1) algorithm. Fascinating. I wish I'd listened more in my mathematics lessons.

Comment: @Richard Hodges Your code computes the (n-1) Fibonacci number. This page shows the closed form solution and several proofs of it. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65011/prove-this-formula-for-the-fibonacci-sequence. Since you know the answer must be an integer, there's a slightly simpler formula you will find on the Wikipedia page involving rounding the first term.

Comment: Or rather ... computes the (n+1) Fibonacci number.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @MFisherKDX Thanks, reading the proofs for the closed form solution of a Fibonacci number really helped me understand more about this problem and my own running time in comparison to this.

Answer (score 0):

Memoisation can make an enormous difference:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <chrono>


long long count_steps(long long n){
    if(n==0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(n < 0){
        return 0;
    }
    return count_steps(n-2) + count_steps(n-1);
}

struct count_steps_algo
{
    using args_type = std::tuple<long long>;
    using result_type = long long;

    template<class Memo, class N>
    result_type operator()(Memo& memo, N&& n)
    {
        if(n==0){
            return 1;
        }
        else if(n < 0){
            return 0;
        }
        return memo(n-2) + memo(n-1);
    }

};

template<class Algo>
struct memoised
{
    using algo_type = Algo;
    using args_type = typename algo_type::args_type;
    using result_type = typename algo_type::result_type;
    using memo_map_type =
    std::unordered_map
            <
                    args_type,
                    result_type,
                    boost::hash<args_type>
            >;

    template<class...Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&...args)
    {
        auto i = memo_map_.find(std::tie(args...));
        if (i != memo_map_.end())
        {
            return i->second;
        }
        auto result = algo_(*this, args...);
        memo_map_.emplace(std::tie(args...), result);
        return result;
    }


    Algo algo_;
    memo_map_type memo_map_;

};


int main()
{
    constexpr int N = 45;
    using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
    auto cs = memoised<count_steps_algo>();
    auto start = clock::now();
    std::cout << "start" << std::endl;
    auto memo_result = cs(N);
    std::cout << "stop" << std::endl;   // compiler optimisation re-orders this on clang!!!
    auto stop = clock::now();
    auto secs = std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1>>(stop - start);

    std::cout << "memoised  : " << memo_result << " took "
              << std::fixed << secs.count() << "s\n";

    auto start2 = clock::now();         // compiler optimisation re-orders this on clang!!!
    std::cout << "start" << std::endl;
    auto raw_result = count_steps(N);
    std::cout << "stop" << std::endl;   // compiler optimisation re-orders this on clang!!!
    auto stop2 = clock::now();
    auto secs2 = std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1>>(stop2 - start2);

    std::cout << "bruteforce: " << raw_result << " took "
              << secs2.count() << "s\n";
}
```

example output:

```
start
stop
memoised  : 1836311903 took 0.000082s
start
stop
bruteforce: 1836311903 took 11.026068s
```

Comment: In OP's case, you don't even need (unordered) `map`, just do the loop in correct order: `long long Fibo(int n)
{
    long long fib[2] = {0, 1};
    for (int i = 0; i != n + 1; ++i) {
        std::tie(fib[0], fib[1]) = std::make_tuple(fib[1], fib[0] + fib[1]);
    }
    return fib[0];
}`